# what's lost while link error "undefined reference" in g++

Tags: c++, gcc

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

While g++ report "error: undefined reference to 'Log::flush()'", it means I lost a source code which define the member function flush of class Log like this:

```
class Log{   
   ... ...   
   int flush();   
   ... ... 
};
```

But if the g++ report "error: undefined reference to 'Log::outFile'", What is lost? There is no `()` so this is not a function, so why is there anything that needs defining?

Comment: did you provide `int Log::flush()` function definition and link it?

Comment: Definition of `Log::outFile` method?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix

Comment: @nameless: No `()`. It's not a function.

Comment: I don't understand.. you practically answered your own question?  the definition of outFile?

Comment: @thang: He has noticed that it is not a function, and does not understand why there is anything to define, because he has not read the chapter about static data members in his C++ book.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, haha that's good sleuthing.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit, Nice catch when the code sample is completely unrelated. Luckily, my link still applies :)

Comment: Not bad huh. This is quite a poor question, with an incomplete testcase and the premise left up to our imaginations. Fortunately I was a private investigator on TV in a previous life...

Answer (score 4):

<sub>Well, isn't this a fun exercise in *GCC diagnostic output jeopardy*!</sub>

---

> But if the g++ report "error: undefined reference to 'Log::outFile'", What is lost?

More than likely, the definition of a static data member of `Log` called `outFile`.

Guessing:

```
class Log
{
   int flush();
   // ... more functions ...

   static std::string outFile;
   // ... more data ...
};
```

You'd need to write:

```
std::string Log::outFile;
```

in precisely one translation unit; put it in a `.cpp` file, probably the one in which you placed the definition for `Log::flush()`.